# Surface Definition From a Normal Vector.

Tags: vectors, surfaces

I have the velocity vectors and positions of n number of bodies in an N-Body system and I want to calculate the center of mass of the whole system.

Since I have the velocity vectors:

Let's say I find the definition of flat surfaces to which each velocity vectors are normal.
Can I consider the intersection of all calculated surfaces as the center of mass of the system?

If yes,

How to calculate the definition of a flat surface which I know the definition of its normal vector?

> What is the definition of a flat surface, if its normal vector is V(x,
> y, z)?

If not,

I am open to other suggestions for my original problem.

Comment: The center of mass does not depend on velocities at all.  It is just the weighted average of the position vectors, weighted by their masses.

Comment: @Ruy, If we add another condition which is "all bodies are in a closed, keplerian, orbit". Can we consider all Velocity vectors must be tangent to the orbit? (must be perpendicular to a line from the center of mass to the body)

Comment: "all Velocity vectors must be tangent to the orbit?" YES. "Must be perpendicular to a line from the center of mass to the body?" NO

Comment: I see where I was wrong. Thank you for correcting me @Ruy.